# DOMContentLoaded never fires, can not use WebComponentsReady

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Using polymer 1.2.3,

In firefox, where the polyfill(webcomponents-lite.js) is used:

`WebComponentsReady` fires to soon, because I `querySelect` and `getElementById` elements that do not exist yet in `initialize`.

```
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
  initialize
    .then(attatchListeners)
```

So I am using `DOMContentLoaded` but it never fires:

```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     initialize
      .then(attatchListeners)
```

Any ideas on how to make initialize run when the elements are available for `querySelect()`?

**Update** I had the listener for `DOMContentLoaded` listen to late.\

Comment: It works for me: http://jsbin.com/damego/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks, I had the DOMContentLoaded listener to late.

Comment: Actually, in firefox that jsbin never does the `alert(e)`